# Singleton instance exist after closing the application from browser

Tags: java, soap, transactions, singleton

I am facing a strange issue in my application.

Application detail-
Its a client server application deployed in websphere,
**Technology**- 
Frontend-JSF
Backend-SOAP and JPA.

1. We have Client that is WEbApp.EAR it is using JSF and SOAP consumer to access SOAP Service.
2. We have ServiceApp.EAR  it is developed using soap Service and Db is accessed with JPA.

Now we have created a singleton class for connection factory.

Now the problem is when we are doing secong time login even after closing the browser. Previous object of singleton class exist.

When we login first time eManager is null and it creates a EntityM instance.
Now we logout or close the browser and re login eManager value is not null.

Please help

Comment: so why a server side object become null because browser is closed ?

Comment: @SabirKhan right server side object exist in memory.how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Until the class is unloaded, possibly until the app server or JVM is shut down, the object will be alive. So the life of a Singleton never depends on the browser.

Comment: can you suggest some solution how to handle this .